# get ID3 tags/titles of mp3 file from URL

Tags: php, android, mp3, id3

Hi there I developing an app and it requires the app to get the titles off the mp3 files. (Mp3 files only) the options are getting then from PHP or from android itself. I have tried the the mediametadata class but it just force closes I can assume that its for only local files. As for PHP, I need to install something I can't remember what but I can't do that since I switch servers very often. I would like something simple :)

Oh and I tried ffmpeg meta retriever library as well works, but turns my app into massive size. So would prefer something tjats lightweight as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Remote MP3 File's ID3 Tags using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055342/reading-remote-mp3-files-id3-tags-using-java)

Comment: It does not solve the issue lol

Comment: Isn't your question about reading ID3 tags from remote mp3 files (also avoiding the download of the entire file)?